# Are Cassandra backups(snapshots) block level backups or meta data backups?

Tags: cassandra

So just wanted to know whether Cassandra backups are block level backups or meta data backups ?

Answer (score 0):

When snapshot is taken cassandra flush the data from memtable to sstable and then hard-link of sstables are made in snapshot directory.
Snapshot directory is made in individual table directory.

**Note:** Cassandra can only restore data from a snapshot when the table schema exists. It is recommended that you also backup the schema.

[More Details](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_takes_snapshot_t.html)